# Scroll to element with FluentAutomation?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, fluentautomation

Is it possible to scroll to an element with [FluentAutomation](http://fluent.stirno.com/) + [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), e.g. to click a button outside of the currently visible area? If so, how?

From browsing the FluentAutomation docs, I can't see any support for this. The problem is that if an element is outside the currently visible area, it can't be interacted with (e.g. clicked) via FluentAutomation.

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: @SonerGönül I simply can't see any support for scrolling via FluentAutomation. If I try to click a non-visible button, FluentAutomation can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use I.Hover(selector) to cause an element to scroll into view. Selenium implicitly handles managing the viewport via what the test is touching.

Comment: I should also note, that the dev version of FluentAutomation should no longer suffer from the 'Element not visible' errors as we have switched our underlying method of clicking items.

This should mean you won't have to take 2 steps if ultimately your goal is to click the thing that is not visible.

Comment: Also added, in dev branch, syntactical sugar to provider an alias for I.Scroll -> I.Hover as the internal implementations would be identical.

Comment: Automatic scrolling upon click sounds excellent, is this how the raw Selenium Webdriver API handles it as well?

Comment: Only if you use the Actions API to trigger the click.